# Add/Append value to specific index in a list

Tags: python, list, append

I have the following list:

```
a = [['628', 'facial-expressions_2868588k.jpg', 'anger', '2'], ['628', 'facial-expressions_2868585k.jpg', 'surprise', '5'], ['628', 'facial-expressions_2868584k.jpg', 'disgust', '6'], ['628', 'facial-expressions_2868582k.jpg', 'fear', '4'], ['dwdii', 'Aaron_Eckhart_0001.jpg', 'neutral', '3'], ['302', 'Aaron_Guiel_0001.jpg', 'happiness', '1'], ['302', 'Aaron_Patterson_0001.jpg', 'neutral', '3'], ['302', 'Aaron_Peirsol_0001.jpg', 'happiness', '1'], ['302', 'Aaron_Peirsol_0002.jpg', 'happiness', '1'], ['302', 'Aaron_Peirsol_0003.jpg', 'happiness', '1'], ['302', 'Aaron_Peirsol_0004.jpg', 'neutral', '3'], ['302', 'Aaron_Pena_0001.jpg', 'neutral', '3']]
```

I want to append/add values to the indexes of this list.
Let's say I want to append `'hi'` to the first index of this list to get the following:

```
a = [['628', 'facial-expressions_2868588k.jpg', 'anger', '2', 'hi'], ['628', 'facial-expressions_2868585k.jpg', 'surprise', '5'], ['628', 'facial-expressions_2868584k.jpg', 'disgust', '6'], ['628', 'facial-expressions_2868582k.jpg', 'fear', '4'], ['dwdii', 'Aaron_Eckhart_0001.jpg', 'neutral', '3'], ['302', 'Aaron_Guiel_0001.jpg', 'happiness', '1'], ['302', 'Aaron_Patterson_0001.jpg', 'neutral', '3'], ['302', 'Aaron_Peirsol_0001.jpg', 'happiness', '1'], ['302', 'Aaron_Peirsol_0002.jpg', 'happiness', '1'], ['302', 'Aaron_Peirsol_0003.jpg', 'happiness', '1'], ['302', 'Aaron_Peirsol_0004.jpg', 'neutral', '3'], ['302', 'Aaron_Pena_0001.jpg', 'neutral', '3']]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `a[0].append('hi')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `a[0].append('hi')` because the list you want to is the 0th index in the list `a`.

Answer (score 1):

`a[0].append('hi')`. Just go from the outer index number to the inner one.
For example if you have the list below:

```
num_list = [1, [2, 3], [4, [5], 6]]
```

Imagine you want to add `0` to have the following:

```
num_list = [1, [2, 3], [4, [5, 0], 6]]
```

In order to do so, you need to do this:

```
num_list[2][1].append(0)
```